# Recent Multicolider SuperDropdown Changes

Tags: support, hot-questions

One of my favorite things about the StackExchange set of sites was always broadening my knowledge of different subjects by going to the Multicolider SuperDropdown and visiting the trending questions, not just on StackOverflow, but from all the sites.  With the most recent change to the top bar, is this now impossible?

Where I would normally see a list of hot questions from various StackExchange sites, I know see just a list of StackExchange sites that I participate in most, followed by other sites.

Comment: Ah, seems like a pretty cut and dry duplicate.  My mistake.  That said, I like the way it used to be much better.  I could access the most popular questions from any page and used them to jump from question to question.